# Que un texto aparezca centrado, con espacio arriba y abajo

Tags: html, css

Estaba resolviendo un ejercicio muy simple y me encontré con un problema en la alineación de los elementos.

Quiero que el `h1` esté centrado. Pero el autor del tutorial utiliza `*{ padding:0; margin: 0;}` para que todo elemento en el documento quede centrado, y eso no parece estar funcionando.

Les detallo el código en html y css. Y añado también una imagen de como sugiere el ebook (con el cual estoy aprendiendo) que debería quedar la página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description" content="A quiz game for ninjas">
      <meta name="author" content="DAZ">
      <title>Quiz Ninja</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1>Quiz Ninja!</h1>
      </header>
      <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Y el documento css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  font: bold 36px/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #c00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[image: Como debería verse]

Cuando ejecuto el html en mi navegador, se ve así. No se preocupen por la funcionalidad Javascript porque la captura del ebook es de una instancia mas avanzada, pero el archivo css sigue siendo el mismo.

[image: Como me quedo a mí]

Comment: Eliminé JavaScript del título y las etiquetas porque no tiene relación con tu problema. Y para que quede claro, en caso que no podamos ver las imégenes, ¿quieres que 'QUIZ NINJA' aparezca centrado, con espacio arriba y abajo?

Comment: si solo tienes eso estilos en el archivo css, es normal que se vea así.

Comment: Si, gracias. Es mi primer post y quizás no lo deje muy claro. Quiero que el h1 este centrado. Pero el autor del tutorial utiliza *{ padding:0; margin: 0;} para que todo elemento en el documento quede centrado y eso no parece estar funcionando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para el ejemplo que propones, es más sencillo y en mi opinión, más legible y comprensible de la siguiente forma.

Tenemos un contenedor principal `<header>` que envuelve a otro contenedor `<h1>`, luego podríamos usar el siguiente css y ahora lo explico:

```css
header {
  background: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

header>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #c00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Quiz Ninja!</h1>
</header>
```

En primer lugar, le doy un color de fondo al contenedor principal `<header>` y un tamaño establecido a tu gusto. De esta forma, obtenemos en mi caso una caja con un `width: 100% y height: 100px`, con color de fondo `#333`.

Ahora, al tener en su interior un `<h1>` y queremos centrarlo y ponerlo en el medio del contenedor verticalmente, he optado por `text-align: center`, que centra horizontalmente los hijos del contenedor al que se lo aplica. De esta forma, al aplicarlo a `<h1>`, el texto hijo de `<h1>` queda centrado.

Luego, le ponemos el tamaño y el tipo de letra con la propiedad font.

Para centrarlo verticalmente, he utilizado `line-height: 100px` (si te fijas es el mismo valor que la altura del contenedor padre de `<h1>`), que hace que el contenedor donde se lo aplicamos tenga una altura de línea con el valor indicado, quedando el contenido en el centro de éste (es como un padding bottom y top a la vez, pero sin hacer cálculos). De esta forma, si el contenedor `<header>` tiene una altura de `100px` y el contenedor hijo `<h1>` tiene un `line-height` de `100px`, el h1 toma la totalidad de la altura del contenedor padre `<header>` y el texto indicado queda centrado.

Por último, ponemos el color indicado y que se transforme en mayúsculas.

y obtenemos lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las alturas se comienzan a contar desde el extremo superior izquierdo del documento? O hay un 0 de coordenadas dentro de cada elemento?

Comment: La altura es dentro de cada elemento padre.

Answer (score 5):

Necesitas dos propiedades en tu hoja de estilo.

La primera, es la que hace que tu texto se vea centrado y es `text-align` y su valor, como podrás imaginar es `center`.

La segunda se llama `padding` y crea un espacio dentro del elemento. Cuando lo usas con un solo argumento, agrega el espacio indicado en los cuatro lados. Cuando lo usas con dos parámetros (*como en este ejemplo*), el primer valor se refiere al espacio arriba y abajo; y el segundo a la izquierda y derecha. Si usas `padding` con cuatro parámetros, se refiere uno a cada lado: arriba, derecha, abajo, izquierda, **en ese orden**.

```css
header {
  font: bold 36px/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #c00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Quiz Ninja!</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para generar el resultado que deseas, metí el header dentro de un center.

Para que no se salga del tamaño, invertí el orden de `36px/120%` a `120%/36px`, y se ve más o menos como quieres.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  font: bold 120%/36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #c00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="A quiz game for ninjas">
  <meta name="author" content="DAZ">
  <title>Quiz Ninja</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <header>
      <h1>Quiz Ninja!</h1>
    </header>
  </center>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Puedes usar el botón `<>` para insertar un fragmente de código funcional en tu respuesta...